# Audio tag ended event listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I had a working event listener for an audio tag before, now when I revisited my old code it isn't working

```
audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){ console.log('end')});
```

Did they change the event listener in new browsers? Is there any alternative way to do it now?

Additionally I created my audio tag with the following line

```
var audio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
```

The code should be something like this but with the console actually logging in the end

```js
var audio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){ console.log('end')});
audio.play();
```

Update: It is working on Firefox but not Chrome, what is the alternative for both?

Comment: It works for me, here in the snippet.

Comment: @Xufox is it logging the word end in the console?

Comment: Yes, it’s working as described.

Comment: @Xufox on firefox it is working, but not on chrome I guess